# What's the best approach for natural language processing of setting a reminder using SpaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, pattern-matching, spacy

I'm working on a project, where using SpaCy, I want a sentence such as "remind me to call my parents on Thursday at 7:00 PM" to have the date and time extracted from it, which would be "Thursday at 7:00 PM" in this case, and I also want the task of the reminder to be extracted ("call my parents"). I was looking for some insight from someone who has more experience using SpaCy and NLP, would the best rule-based approach be to use, RegEx, SpaCy matcher, or EntityRuler? Or is rule-based the best approach for this at all? Thanks for the help.

```
task = " ".join([token.text for token in doc if token.pos_ in ["VERB", "NOUN", "PROPN", "PRON"]])
date = " ".join([token.text for token in doc if token.pos_ in ["NUM"]])
time = " ".join([token.text for token in doc if token.pos_ in ["TIME"]])
```

i initially tried like this and it obviously didnt work lol.